# Troubleshooting python code to scrape and store PDF text

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, beautifulsoup, pypdf

The following code searches through [the main URL](https://covapp.vancouver.ca/councilMeetingPublic/CouncilMeetings.aspx?SearchType=3) and enters the 'Council' hyperlink to extract text from the Minutes documents on each page (stored in PDFs, and extracted using PyPDF2).

The problem I'm having is that the code is supposed to loop through n pages to pull PDFs, but the output only returns the first PDF. I'm not sure what's happening, as minutes_links does store the correct number of links to the PDF files, but in the for loop to extract pdf_name and pages_text, only the first link is pulled and stored.

```
import os
import time
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Create a headless chromedriver to query and perform action on webpages like a browser
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Main url
my_url = (
    "https://covapp.vancouver.ca/councilMeetingPublic/CouncilMeetings.aspx?SearchType=3"
)


def get_n_first_pages(n: int):
    """Get the html text for the first n pages

    Args:
        n (int): The number of pages we want

    Returns:
        List[str]: A list of html text
    """

    # Initialize the variables containing the pages
    pages = []

    # We query the web page with our chrome driver.
    # This way we can iteratively click on the next link to get all the pages we want
    driver.get(my_url)
    # We append the page source code
    pages.append(driver.page_source)

    # Then for all subsequent pages, we click on next and wait to get the page
    for _ in range(1, n):
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "#LiverpoolTheme_wt93_block_wtMainContent_RichWidgets_wt132_block_wt28"
        ).click()
        # Wait for the page to load
        time.sleep(1)
        # Append the page
        pages.append(driver.page_source)
    return pages


def get_pdf(link: str):
    """Get the pdf text, per PDF pages, for a given link.

    Args:
        link (str): The link where we can retrieve the PDF

    Returns:
        List[str]: A list containing a string per PDF pages
    """

    # We extract the file name
    pdf_name = link.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

    # We get the page containing the PDF link
    # Here we don't need the chrome driver since we don't have to click on the link
    # We can just get the PDF using requests after finding the href
    pdf_link_page = requests.get(link)
    page_soup = soup(pdf_link_page.text, "lxml")
    # We get all <a> tag that have href attribute, then we select only the href
    # containing min.pdf, since we only want the PDF for the minutes
    pdf_link = [
        urljoin(link, l.attrs["href"])
        for l in page_soup.find_all("a", {"href": True})
        if "min.pdf" in l.attrs["href"]
    ]
    # There is only one PDF for the minutes so we get the only element in the list
    pdf_link = pdf_link[0]

    # We get the PDF with requests and then get the PDF bytes
    pdf_bytes = requests.get(pdf_link).content
    # We load the bytes into an in memory file (to avoid saving the PDF on disk)
    p = BytesIO(pdf_bytes)
    p.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

    # Now we can load our PDF in PyPDF2 from memory
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)
    count = read_pdf.numPages
    pages_txt = []
    # For each page we extract the text
    for i in range(count):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
        pages_txt.append(page.extractText())

    # We return the PDF name as well as the text inside each pages
    return pdf_name, pages_txt


# Get the first 16 pages, you can change this number
pages = get_n_first_pages(16)


# Initialize a list to store each dataframe rows
df_rows = []

# We iterate over each page
for page in pages:
    page_soup = soup(page, "lxml")

    # Here we get only the <a> tag inside the tbody and each tr
    # We avoid getting the links from the head of the table
    all_links = page_soup.select("tbody tr a")
    # We extract the href for only the links containing council (we don't care about the
    # video link)
    minutes_links = [x.attrs["href"] for x in all_links if "council" in x.attrs["href"]]

    #
    for link in minutes_links:
        pdf_name, pages_text = get_pdf(link)

        df_rows.append(
            {
                "PDF_file_name": pdf_name,
                # We join each page in the list into one string, separting them with a line return
                "PDF_text": "\n".join(pages_text),
            }
        )

        break
    break

# We create the data frame from the list of rows
df = pd.DataFrame(df_rows)
```

The desired output is a dataframe that looks like this:

| PDF_file_name | PDF_text |
| --- | --- |
| spec20210729min | [[' \n \n \n \n \n \n \nSPECIAL COUNCIL MEET\nING MINUTES\n \n \nJULY 29, 2021\n \n \nA Special Meeting of the Council\n \nof the City of Vancouver\n \nw |
| spec20210802min | [[' \n \n \n \n \n \n \nSPECIAL COUNCIL MEET\nING MINUTES\n \n \nAUGUST 2, 2021\n \n \nA Special Meeting of the Council\n \nof the City of Vancouver\n \nw |

Right now, I can get the first one in there, but not any subsequent files. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your two for loops, you have a `break` command.

The `break` command tells the for loop to stop executing and move on to the next block of code. So, each of your for loops only end up running once.

Remove these two break statements, and it should work as intended.

P.S - I have not tested this, I will remove this answer if it doesn't work